# Electrostatic potential due to a pure dipole

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

For a pure dipole, is the electrostatic potential given by the dipole term in the multipole expansion exact for all $r$ (position vector from the origin)? Or is it exact only far away from the dipole? If it's exact for all $r$, then what if the origin itself is far away from the dipole?

Comment: You can check this yourself using a pen and some paper.

Comment: You need to be sure about what you mean by "a pure dipole". In the context of a multipole expansion, the dipole term represents the field (or potential) due to equal and opposite charges infinitesimally close together. Is this the "pure dipole" that you mean, or do you mean equal and opposite charges a finite distance apart?  If the latter, then the field or potential given by the dipole term of the multipole expansion is accurate only far from the charges – see the comment of my2cts.

Comment: I mean two equal and opposite charges in the limit as the distance goes to zero and the charge of each goes to infinity with the sum still zero.

Comment: After thinking a bit I concluded that it's exact if and only if the multipole expansion converges, which means that if the pure dipole is at the origin it's valid for all r bigger that zero, but when it's away from the origin it's exact when the series converges, that it, when r much larges that the distance from the origin to the dipole. Is this corrct?

Comment: No. Whether the dipole is at the origin or not has nothing at all to do with your question. This is just a matter of translation or choice of coordinates.

Comment: I don't know, I'm lost . Is there any suggested reading that might clarify this matter?